# LinearLayouts Overlapping (in RecyclerView's row_layout.xml)

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, overlap

I tried searching multiple StackOverflow posts for this, as there seem to be many.
I tried many of the solutions including:

Changing the ordering/nesting
Adding android:layout_above
Adding android:align_bottom
Adding android:align_ParentBottom

etc...

The XML looks fine so not sure why its overlapping?

Picture:   [image]

row_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".45"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameOfBusinessET"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.55"
            android:hint="@string/nameOfBusiness"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:textColorHint="@color/grey" />

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".45"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bizLocationET"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.55"
            android:hint="Location"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:textColorHint="@color/grey" />



 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add orientation for LinearLayout by default its horizontal

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this layout :**

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/temp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/bizLocationET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:hint="Location"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/temp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:hint="Name of business"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

> Take **one** `Verical Linear layout` -> **Two** `horizontal linear layout`
>        In every horizontal layout take `image view` and `edittext`.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `RelativeLayout` and `RelativeLayout` is a view group that displays child views in relative positions. The position of each view can be specified as relative to sibling elements (such as to the left-of or below another view) or in positions relative to the parent `RelativeLayout` area (such as aligned to the bottom, left or center).

Change your

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        ......
</RelativeLayout>
```

with

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    .....
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="100dp"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".45"
        android:src="@drawable/user" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameOfBusinessET"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.55"
        android:hint="@string/nameOfBusiness"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".45"
        android:src="@drawable/user" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bizLocationET"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.55"
        android:hint="Location"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Hope you are looking for this , change your parent `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` with an orientation vertical.

Also `LinearLayout` means you can align views one by one (vertically/ horizontally).By default `LinearLayout` is Horizontally

Where as 
`RelativeLayout` means based on relation of views from its parents and other views.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one attribute in your LinearLayout having id `rl2` `android:layout_below="@+id/rl"`

so your layout would be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".45"
            android:src="@drawable/user"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameOfBusinessET"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.55"
            android:hint="@string/done"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".45"
            android:src="@drawable/user"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bizLocationET"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.55"
            android:hint="Location"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```